# Need help in complex sql query

Tags: sql

Say you have 2 columns you are grouping by and getting a count:

```
select col1, col2, count(*) 
from yourtable
group by col1, col2
```

Your col2 will be unique, but you will get repeated col1's.  To avoid this, you can:

```
select decode(lag(col1,1,0) over (order by col1),col1,' ',col1) col1, col2, cnt
from
(select col1, col2, count(*) cnt
 from yourtable
 group by col1, col2)
```

This will compare the prior value -- lag(col1,1,0) over (order by col1) -- with the current value.
If it is the same, it returns a blank instead.

---

My question

I am trying to write a SELECT as below to display data in the given format at the end of the question.
Its not working,please help

```
SELECT DECODE (LAG (firstname, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY firstname),
               firstname, ' ',
               firstname
              ) firstname,
       DECODE (LAG (emplid, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY emplid),
               emplid, ' ',
               emplid
              ) emplid,
       DECODE (LAG (tplan_name, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY tplan_name),
               tplan_name, ' ',
               tplan_name
              ) tplan_name,
    completed_cdt_act,             ----->This is 1 more calculated field corresponding to each TPLAN_NAME

       DECODE (LAG (t_objective_id, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY t_objective_id),
               t_objective_id, ' ',
               t_objective_id
              ) t_objective_id,
       completed_activities
  FROM (SELECT test_cp.firstname, test_op.emplid,tp.tplan_name,
            fn_tp_get_cmpltd_act_cnt (tp.tplan_id,
                                 test_cp.person_id,
                                 test_o.org_id
                                ) completed_cdt_act, 
               test_tpo.t_objective_id,
               (  fn_tp_obj_comp_req_act_cdt (test_lp.lp_person_id,
                                              tp.tplan_id,
                                              test_tpo.t_objective_id,
                                              tp.is_credit_based
                                             )
                + fn_tp_obj_comp_opt_act_cdt (test_lp.lp_person_id,
                                              tp.tplan_id,
                                              test_tpo.t_objective_id,
                                              tp.is_credit_based
                                             )
               ) completed_activities,
                tpobjact.activity_id activity_id,  -----> Again ,each objective_id we select CAN have multiple activity_ids.The remaining fields gives the activity_name,their status

            lr.catalog_item_name,
       fn_tp_get_act_type (tpobjact.is_preferred,
                           tpobjact.is_required) status,
       lr.catalog_item_type activity_type, lr.delivery_method,  lr.status status1,
          FROM test_learning_plan test_lp,
               test_training_plan tp,
               test_person test_cp,
               test_org_person test_op,
               test_org test_o
               test_tp_objective test_tpo,
               test_train_obj_activity tpobjact,

       test_learning_record lr,
       test_training_objective obj,
         WHERE test_lp.lp_person_id = '1'
           AND test_cp.person_id = test_lp.lp_person_id
           AND tp.tplan_id = test_lp.lp_catalog_hist_id
           AND test_op.o_person_id = test_cp.person_id
           and test_o.org_id = test_op.O_ORG_ID
           AND test_tpo.tplan_id = tp.tplan_id
           and  lr.tp_ref_lp_id = test_lp.learning_plan_id
   AND lr.lr_catalog_history_id = tpobjact.activity_id


   AND tpobjact.t_objective_id = test_tpo.t_objective_id);





******************************************************************************************************
The display format is something like this.

firstname   emplid  Tplan name  completed(for TP)   Objective Name  Credits (for objective) Number of activities completed(for objective)   activity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         name   activity completion status

U1  U1                 TP1                                       5                  
                                                                          OBJ1                     4                          3                                    C1         PASSED
                                                                                                                                                               C2       PASSED
                                                                                                                                                               C3   WAIVED
                            T1  ENROLLED
                            T2  ENROLLED
                                                                                 OBJ2   3              2        
                                                                                         S1 ENROLLED
                            S2  PASSED
                            T3  WAIVED
U1  U1  TP2                 C4  INPROGRESS
            50  OBJ11   50  30  C11 PASSED
                            C22 PASSED
                            C33 WAIVED
                            T11 ENROLLED
                            T22 ENROLLED
                OBJ22   40  20      
                            S11 ENROLLED
                            S22 PASSED
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way to approach this is to simplify things.

So start like this.

1) What do you want to display - i.e. what is the list of

If you want a list of employees with "some stuff" against each employee, then write a script that just gets the list of employees.

2) Add a bit of complexity

If you need to know the "number of something" an employee has done, add that in. You have the option to a) Join the tables and use grouping b) performing a sub-select statement to just get the value. Your choice will depend on performance considerations.

3) Got that working? Add a bit more complexity - what's the next thing you need for each employee that you need to obtain... (i.e. iterate around to add each complex item, knowing that it works at each stage).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance.I worked on gradually adding one table after another exactly as the data is required stepwise.But,still I am facing issues with displaying them.

I know what data to be selected but I am stuck because these data selected has to displayed in a particular format given.

I also stepwise used LAG with decode to get this required display and eliminate the repeated values.But,still there are many issues I am not able to do and would appreciate if you please have a look at my SELECT above and help me writing it to get the display as needed.

Thanks Again